# Include Boost library in C++ cross platform project using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake, compilation

I need to include a Boost library (specifically `Context`) in a C++ project that uses CMAKE as build management system.
Since, given the source code of the repository, the project needs to be built using `cmake` and `make` without any other software or library installation in the target system (unix,windows or whatever), I need to configure Cmake to take the source of Boost from my repository, compile it, and link it to my project without installing Boost library in the target system in a separated step.
Is this feasible?

Comment: It's definitely possible (I use a build system configured that way every day), but I didn't set it up so unfortunately I couldn't say how exactly it is done.

Comment: What do you mean by `take the source of Boost from my repository`? Downloading boost?  Or using the headers included in your repository?

Comment: @eozd I mean that the project should be self included. Since in the target system, the project should be built using cmake, I guess the sources of the Boost libraries have to be included in my repository together with my source code so that they can be compiled together.

Answer (score 1):

`CMake` has a specific module for handling boost` libraries, see [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindBoost.html).

The `CMakeLists.txt` file normally includes something like this to link to a `boost` library:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS context )
if(Boost_FOUND)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE Boost::context)
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

This will just link the `boost::context` library. You must either build the boost::context lib files as suggested in @Hugo's answer, download them from somewhere like [here](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/binaries/) or use a package manager to install them on linux.

If `Context` was `header only`, you would only require:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS boost)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

In either case you can include the `boost::context` files in your project and then set the variables `BOOST_ROOT` or `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` as described in the [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindBoost.html) documentation.

Comment: I understood that the FindBoost module finds boost libraries on the system, as a binaries, not source code. Plus, Context is not header only as described here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html Anyway I tried the whole day yesterday to use FindBoost without good results.

Comment: I'm sorry @Archimedis I thought that `boost::context` was header only because my system didn't build it despite being set to `build-all`... I've edited my answer and suggested a few different ways for you to get the binaries for boost context. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ExternalProject_Add, see the documentation at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Take a look at the link below for an example of use which compiles boost

https://github.com/arnaudgelas/ExternalProject/blob/master/External-Boost.cmake

HTH